# Getting Eval Error while trying get values from JSON

Tags: qgis-3, geojson, labeling, error

I've got a point layer GeoJSON from OpenStreetMap for tram routes. In **@relations** field there is JSON. I want to get numbers of tram routes as a list (3, 10, 21, 6...so on) for points labeling. Using `map_get` function for creating expression but getting Eval Error. Why can't this map be converted and why can't I access values by keys?

UPD. [Center_tram_stop.geojson](https://disk.yandex.ru/d/j5ucsfJ0Q5x4xw).

[image: Eval Error]

Comment: @MrXsquared, please have a look for update. I've attached the link to the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About *Why can't this map be converted*: The fieldtype is `string`. And this string already **represents** an `array/list` **but isnt one**, thats why it cannot be converted to one. Also it represents an `array/list` of `maps/dictionaries`, not a single `map/dictionary`, thats why also `hstore_to_map()` cannot be used.

So far I could not find a way to turn the list-representation of type string into an actual list using QGIS-Expressions *(in Python you can do it using `json.loads(yourstring)`)*. So I wrote a custom function for the whole task. It expects a list-representation of type string as input containing dictionaries as values. Then it loops over these dictionaries looking for a given key to search for. While doing that it goes down to three sub-dictionaries. If it finds the key, it appends its value to a list. So its usage is:

- Input 1: list-of-dictionaries-representation as string, e.g. `'['k1':'v1','k2':{'k2a':'v2a','k2b':'v2b'},'k3':'v3']'`
- Input 2: the key to search for
- Output: array/list of values of that key

So in your case, use it as: `keyvalues_from_nested_dict("@relations",'ref')`

[image]

To convert the array values to integers you could use e.g. `array_foreach(keyvalues_from_nested_dict("@relations",'ref'),to_int(@element))`

The function:

```py
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
import json

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom', referenced_columns=[])
def keyvalues_from_nested_dict(inp, k, feature, parent):
    outp = []
    li = json.loads(inp) # convert the string representation of a list to an actual list
    for dic in li: # iterate over this list of dictionaries
        for k1,v1 in dic.items(): # iterate over the first dict
            if k1 == k: # if the current key is the key we are searching for, append its value to the outputlist
                outp.append(v1)
            if type(v1) == dict: # if the current value is of type dict, iterate over this sub-dictionary
                for k2,v2 in v1.items():
                    if k2 == k:
                        outp.append(v2)
                    if type(v2) == dict:
                        for k3,v3 in v2.items():
                            if k3 == k:
                                outp.append(v3)
    return outp
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for your help! It's sad that there are no actual QGIS expressions to get this kind of values from OSM data. Your instructions are complete and helpful. I have never used functions for expression creating before . At the same time I got a reason to see what exactly json.loads() does. Do not know why, but in my case I was forced to make small changes to get points labels visible: array_to_string(array_foreach(keyvalues_from_nested_dict("@relations",'ref'), to_string(@element)))